# Angular elements | Create separated build for each component

Tags: angular, build, element, web-component, angular-elements

I have a regular Angular project and I want to convert it in an **Angular elements** project.

My main goal is to have separated build files for each component/element.

- *login/main.js*
- *header/main.js*
- *footer/main.js*
  ....

At this moment and following the Angular documentation I have achieved this but when I build my project I get a single *main.js* file that I need to import in the hosting project.

1st question. As I will be adding lots of elements into the Angular project, if I follow this approach, this will be inefficient as every time that I use an Angular element the entire *main.js* file (containing all the elements) will be loaded. Is this assumption correct?

So, to avoid that I need to build the project in a way that I can have separated Angular elements.
I've been [following this article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/creating-web-component-with-angular-element-angular-11-1c53be854a07) but no luck so far. My element doesn't render into the hosting project.

Questions:

- How to build separated Angular elements into different folders or files?
- If all the elements are inside one single file, does this mean that every time a element is called, the entire file will be loaded?
- Is there a different way to achieve this?

If someone has experienced this issue and can give me some directions I would appreciate.